# Prob 9, Sec 26, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to prove the generalised tube lemma?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The *tube lemma* is as follows:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $Y$ be compact. Let $x \in X$. If $N$ is an open set in $X \times Y$ such that $x \times Y \subset N$, then there is an open set $W$ in $X$ such that $x \in W$ and $W \times Y \subset N$.

This is Lemma 26.8 in *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition. I think I'm clear about it and its proof.

Now how (to use the above result ) to derive the following?

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $X$ and $Y$, respectively; let $N$ be an open set in $X \times Y$ such that $A \times B \subset N$. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are compact. Then there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ and $Y$, respectively such that 
>   $$A \times B \subset U \times V \subset N.$$

My effort:

(Based upon the valuable feedback from @GregoryGrant. )

> Fix an $a \in A$.
>
> Then, for each $b \in B$, there exists an open set $U_{a, b}$ in $X$ and there exists an open set $V_{a,b}$ in $Y$ such that 
>   $$a \times b \in U_{a, b} \times V_{a, b} \subset N. \tag{0} $$
>
> In this way, we obtain a covering $\left\{ \ V_{a, b} \ \colon\  b \in B\  \right\}$ of $B$ by sets open in $Y$. Since $B$ is compact, there are finitely many of these sets, say,  $V_{a, b_1}, \ldots, V_{a, b_n}$ such that 
>   $$B \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n V_{a, b_j}. \tag{1} $$
>
> Let us put $$V_a \colon= \bigcup_{j=1}^n V_{a, b_j} \tag{2} $$ 
>   and 
>   $$U_a \colon= \bigcap_{j=1}^n U_{a, b_j}. \tag{3} $$
>
> Then $U_a$ is open in $X$, $V_a$ is open in $Y$, $a \in U_a$, and $B \subset V_a$. Hence $$ a \times B \subset U_a \times V_a. \tag{4} $$
>
> Moreover, if $x \times y \in U_a \times V_a$, then $x \in U_a$ and $y \in V_a$; so $x \in U_{a, b_j}$ for *each* $j = 1, \ldots, n$ [Refer to (3) above.] and $y \in V_{a, b_k}$ for *some* $k = 1, \ldots, n$ [Refer to (2) above.]; thus $x \times y \in U_{a, b_k} \times V_{a, b_k}$. But by virtue of (0) above 
>   $$U_{a, b_k} \times V_{a, b_k} \subset N.$$
>   So $x \times y \in N$. Hence we have shown that $$ U_a \times V_a \subset N. \tag{5} $$
>
> Therefore, by (4) and (5) we can conclude that, for each element $a \in A$, we have a basis element $U_a \times V_a$ for the product topology on $X \times Y$ such that 
>   $$a \times B \subset U_a \times V_a \subset N. \tag{6} $$
>
> Now $\left\{\ U_a \ \colon \ a \in A \  \right\}$ is a covering of $A$ by sets open in $X$; so there are finitely many of them to cover $A$; that is, there are finitely many sets, say, $U_{a_1}, \ldots, U_{a_m}$  open in  $X$ such that 
>   $$A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m U_{a_i}. \tag{7} $$
>
> Let's take 
>   $$U \colon= \bigcup_{i-1}^m U_{a_i} \tag{8} $$
>   and 
>   $$V \colon= \bigcap_{i=1}^m V_{a_i}. \tag{9} $$
>   Then the set $U$ is open in $X$ and the set $V$ is open in $Y$.
>
> Now we show that $U \times V \subset N$. Let $x \times y \in U \times V$. Then $x \in U$ and $y \in V$. So $x \in U_{a_r}$ for *some* $r = 1, \ldots, m$ [Refer to (8) above.] and $y \in V_{a_i}$ for *each* $i = 1, \ldots, m$ [Refer to (9) above.]. Thus, $x \times y \in U_{a_r} \times V_{a_r}$. But by virtue of (6) above 
>   $$ U_{a_r} \times V_{a_r} \subset N. $$  So
>   $x \times y \in N$, showing that $U \times V \subset N$.
>
> Now we show that $A \times B \subset U \times V$. If $a \times b \in A \times B$, then $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. So $a \in U_{a_s}$ for *some* $s = 1, \ldots, m$ [Refer to (7) above.] and $b \in V_{a_i}$ for *each* $i = 1, \ldots, m$ [Refer to (6) and (9) above.]. Thus [Refer to (8) and (9) above.] $a \in U$ and $b \in V$. So $a \times b \in U \times V$ and thus $A \times B \subset U\times V$, as required.
>
> From the preceding two paragraphs we have obtained 
>   $$ A \times B \subset U \times V \subset N. $$
>   Moreover, $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.

Is this proof correct now?

My initial attempt:

> For any $a \in A$ and for any $b \in B$, we have $a \times B \subset N$ and $A \times b \subset N$.
>
> Since $a \times b \in N$, there is an open set $U_a$ in $X$ and an open set $V_b$ in $Y$ such that $a \times b \in U_a \times V_b \subset N$.
>
> Now $\{U_a \colon a \in A \}$ is a covering of $A$ by sets open in $X$. So there are finitely many points $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ such that 
>   $$A \subset \cup_{i=1}^m U_{a_i}.$$
>
> Similarly, $\{V_b \colon b \in B \}$ is a covering of $B$ by sets open in $Y$, and since $B$ is compact, therefore there are finitely many points $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ such that 
>   $$B \subset \cup_{j=1}^n V_{b_j}.$$

Can we take 
$$U \colon= \cup_{i=1}^m U_{a_i} \ \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ \ V \colon= \cup_{j=1}^n V_{b_j}?$$

Comment: \emph is not defined, but if you want to put something in italics you can just put asterisks around it and it will format as italic.

Comment: To your question "Can we take $U=\cup_{i=1}^n U_{a_i}$    and    $V=\cup_{i=1}^n V_{b_i}$?"  The answer is no.  That may not be contained in $N$.  You should be able to concoct a counter-example fairly easily.  Just pick any diagonally oriented shape in the plane.

Comment: In your second approach you say "Let $U_a:=\cap_{j=1}^nU_{b_j}$. Then $a\in U_a$".  That's not necessarily true, in fact you may have $\cap_{j=1}^nU_{b_j}=\emptyset$.  But you're on the right track, the trick is to use just the $U_{a_i}$'s that contain $a$.  That's basically the approach of the answer posted below.

Comment: @Gregory Grant, In the alternative method, the sets $U_b$ and $V_b$ have been chosen in such a manner that $a \times b \in U_b \times V_b \subset N$, so that $a \in  U_b$. Please have a look at my post once again.

Comment: I went through your proof somewhat carefully and it seems to work.  It's basically the same idea as my proof but a bit more direct because it avoids using the fact that the product of two compacts is compact.  Otherwise, as far as I can tell it's correct.

Comment: I do like your proof.

Comment: @Gregory Grant, thank you.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I've just edited my post to improve readability. Can you please take time reviewing it and comment on whether or not it is any better now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's cleaner to split the proof into a new tube lemma and the actual proof, where both re-use the same proof idea as Munkres' Tube lemma formulation.

Extend the tube lemma first: Let $X,Y$ be any spaces. If $x \in X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ is compact and $\{x\} \times B \subseteq N$, where $N$ is open in $X \times Y$, then there are open sets $O_x \subseteq X$ containing $x$ and $O_B \subseteq Y$ open with $B \subseteq O_B$, such that $O_x \times O_B \subseteq N$. I'll call this the "real" tube lemma. If you study the proof in Munkres, this is what he actually showed there. (Note that it's a bit stronger as we can take $B= Y$ if $Y$ is compact, to get his version.)

Proof: just follow the proof in Munkres: For every $b \in B$ pick $U_b \subseteq X$ open containing $x$ and $V_b \subseteq Y$ containing $b$ such that $U_b \times V_b \subseteq N$. Finitely many $V_{b_1}, \ldots V_{b_m}$ also cover $B$ by compactness, and then define $O_B = \cup_{i=1}^n V_{b_i}$ and $O_x = \cap_{i=1}^n U_{b_i}$. Then just as in Munkres proof $O_x \times O_B \subseteq N$ ($(p,q) \in O_x \times O_B$ implies $q \in V_{b_j}$ for some $j$ and then $p \in U_{b_j}$ as well, and $(p,q) \in U_{b_j} \times V_{b_j} \subseteq N$ by their definition.)

Now to prove the original statement:

So we have $A \times B \subseteq N$. For every $a \in A$ we apply the "real" tube lemma above to $\{a\}$ and $B$, to find $O_a$ open containing $a$ and $O_B(a)$ containing $B$ such that $O_a \times O_B(a) \subseteq N$. Then again, finitely many $O_a$ cover $A$ by compactness of $A$, say $O_{a_1}, \ldots O_{a_n}$, and then define (following the same idea again) $U := \cup_{i=1}^n O_{a_i}$ which is open and contains $A$ (as they form a subcover) and $V = \cap_{i=1}^n O_B(a_i)$ which is an open neighbourhood of $B$ by finiteness.
Now $U \times V \subseteq N$: if $(p,q) \in U \times V$, then $p \in O_{a_j}$ for some $j \in \{1,\ldots n \}$ and then $q \in V \subseteq O_B(a_j)$ and again $(p,q) \in O_{a_j} \times O_B(a_j) \subseteq N$ as required.

This proof set-up is exactly like the proof that in Hausdorff spaces are we can separate two disjoint compact sets by open sets, where we use a lemma to separate $x$ and a disjoint compact set $B$ first, and then prove the full result using the same idea. It's slightly easier on the notation I think.

Comment: thank you for your wonderful answer! Can you please have a look at my post once again and comment on whether my proof is the same as yours? Also, can you please comment on whether or not you agree to the edits I've made to your post? Can I contact you off Math Stack Exchange via email or through WhatsApp to discuss a couple of things not related to the questions here?

Comment: I think saaqib and Gregory are not active. How to show $U_{x_i} \times V_{y_j} \subseteq N$? This fact used in Gregory Grant answer.

Answer (score 2):

We have $A\times B\subseteq N\subseteq X\times Y$, where $A$ and $B$ are compact. For each $(x,y)\in A\times B$, we know there is a basic open set $U_x\times V_y$ where $x\in U_x$ is open in $X$ and $y\in V_y$ is open in $Y$, and $(x,y)\in U_x\times V_y\subseteq N$.

The product of compact spaces  is compact, so $A\times B$ is compact.  Thus $\exists$ a finite subset $U_{x_1}\times V_{y_1},\dots,U_{x_n}\times V_{y_n}$ of $\{U_x\times V_y\mid x\in A, y\in B\}$ such that $A\times B\subseteq (U_{x_1}\times V_{y_1})\cup\dots\cup (U_{x_n}\times V_{y_n})$.

Now for each $x\in A$, let 
$$E_x=\bigcap_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}, \ x\in U_{x_i}}U_{x_i}$$
and, for each  $y\in B$, let 
$$F_y=\bigcap_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}, \  y\in V_{y_i}}V_{y_i}.$$
In words, $E_x$ is the intersection of all of the $U_{x_i}$ that contain $x$, and $F_y$ is the intersection of all of the $V_{y_i}$ that contain $y$.

Since there are only a finite number of $U_{x_i}$ and $V_{y_i}$, $E_x\times F_y$ is open for all $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and the set $\{E_x\times F_y\mid x\in A, y\in B\}$ is a finite set.

Let $U=\cup E_x$ and $V=\cup F_y$.  Let $(a,b)\in A\times B$.  Then $(a,b)\in E_a\times F_b$, so 
$$A\times B\subseteq \cup_{(x,y)\in A\times B} E_x\times F_y=(\cup E_x)\times(\cup F_y) = U\times V. \tag{UNCLEAR}$$
Now for each $(x,y)\in A\times B$, $\exists$ $U_{x_i}$, $V_{y_j}$ such that $(x,y)\in U_{x_i}\times V_{y_j}\subseteq N$.

Thus $E_x\times F_y\subseteq U_{x_i}\times V_{y_j}\subseteq N$.  Thus $E_x\times F_y\subseteq N$ for all $(x,y)\in A\times B$.  Thus $\cup_{(x,y)\in A\times B} E_x\times F_y\subseteq N$.  Since $\cup_{(x,y)\in A\times B} E_x\times F_y=(\cup E_x) \times (\cup F_y)=U\times V$, we have shown $U\times V\subseteq N$.   Thus $U$ and $V$ have the required properties $A\times B\subseteq U\times V\subseteq N$.

Comment: I've made some edits to your answer. Do you agree to these edits? Moreover, I've not been able to follow your proof beginning with the first equality in the chain that I've tagged "UNCLEAR". So could you please make your post a little easier to understand than it already is by improving the spacing / formatting, including more detail, etc.?

Comment: Your proof is insane. My first attempt was exactly same as first two paragraph but couldn’t construct $U$ and $V$. I want to ask, How do you get $U_{x_i} \times V_{y_j} \subseteq N$?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Do you know why $U_{x_i} \times V_{y_j} \subseteq N$?