# Argument using compactness to show continuity

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, compactness

I'm reading *Introduction to smooth manifolds (2nd edition)* of John Lee. At page 476 in the proof of lemma 18.8 I don't understand the following sentence

> Since $G(x_0,t) = G(x_0, 0) = H(x_0, 1) = H_\sigma (x_0, 1) \in U$ for all $t \in I$, a simple compactness argument shows that there exist $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $\lVert x - x_0 \rVert < \delta_2$ implies $G(x, t) \in U$ for all $t \in I$.

I don't see what is the compactness argument he use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as the *tube lemma*. See for example [Prob 9, Sec 26, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to prove the generalised tube lemma?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1278681)

We have $\{x_0\} \times I \subset G^{-1}(U)$. Thus there exists an open neighborhhod $N$ of $x_0$ such that $N \times I \subset G^{-1}(U)$. Now you can finish the proof of Lee's statement.

Answer (score 1):

Supose the conclusion fails. Then there exists a sequence $x_n \to x_0$ and some points $t_n \in I$ such that $G(x_n,t_n) \in U^{c}$ for each $n$.  There is a subsequence $(t_{n_i})$ of $(t_n)$ convergeing to some point $t \in I$. By continuity of $G$ and closedness of $U^{c}$ we get $G(x_0,t)=\lim G(x_{n_i},t_{n_i}) \in U^{c}$ which is a contradiction.